# Static variable declaration is superclass - Java

Tags: java

I have the following program:

```
class Vehicle{  
  static int speed=50;  
  Vehicle(){
      this.speed=speed;
  }
}  


class Bike4 extends Vehicle{  
  int speed=100;  

  void display(){  
   System.out.println(Vehicle.speed);//will print speed of Vehicle now  
  }  
  public static void main(String args[]){  
   Bike4 b=new Bike4();  
   b.display();  
   }  
}
```

Supposing I don't want to use the keyword "super" and I simply call the function "Vehicle.speed" why do I have to change the type of the variable speed in the superclass to static? What would happen if I run the program without using the static keyword? (again, supposing it compiles)

Comment: Why are you making this variable static in the first place?

Comment: What do you mean by "simply call the function Vehicle.speed"? That's a field, not a function. And `static` isn't a *type*, it's a modifier...

Comment: I think you should review the class notes about class (static) vs. instance (non-static) fields. `Vehicle.speed` as you wrote it is not the speed of a given vehicle. It's the speed of all vehicles, which makes no sense.

Answer (score 1):

Because you're defining a different speed for Bike4 as opposed to the parent Vehicle, it looks like you want to change the derived value.  A static variable won't work because it belongs to the class, not the instance.  I think you want something like this instead:

```
public class Vehicle{  
    protected int speed;  
    Vehicle(int speed) {
        this.speed=speed;
    }
}  


public class Bike4 extends Vehicle {
    public Bike4(int speed) {
        super(speed);
    }

    void display() {  
        System.out.println(speed);
    }
    public static void main(String args[]) {  
        Bike4 b=new Bike4(100);  
        b.display();  
    }  
}
```